# Pandas GroupBy with mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

The below code works for the total of each column, but I want to work out the mean for each species.

```
# Read data file into array
data = numpy.genfromtxt('data/iris.csv', delimiter=',')
# picking the first column of data
firstcol = data[:,0]
meanfirstcol = numpy.mean(data[:,0]) #defining meanfirstcol
print("Mean of First Column is:", meanfirstcol)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With pandas, this is pretty easy. You'd just need to `groupby` on the `species` column -

```
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
```

```
df.groupby('species').mean()
            sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width
species                                                         
setosa             5.006        3.428         1.462        0.246
versicolor         5.936        2.770         4.260        1.326
virginica          6.588        2.974         5.552        2.026
```

Comment: In your case, load your data as `import pandas as pd; df = pd.read_csv(
         'data/iris.csv', 
         header=None, 
         names=['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width', 'species']
    )`